# Is there a performance analysis tool like little eye for android for iOS applications?

Tags: android, iphone, ios, testing, performance-testing

I am new to iOS development and probabily don't know all of the tools that are available in market.

I need to get a time based analysis of logs and resource(CPU, memory, network) consumption. I am using Little Eye tool for my android applications but can't find anything for iOS.

http://www.littleeye.co/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple includes a tool called [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) that does exactly what you're looking for